# Confusion related to fmincon function in matlab

Tags: convex-optimization

I was reading this help section of matlab's fmincon function that uses interior point algorithm for solving an optimization problem.
It says the following optimization problem

[image]

is replaced by

[image]

To solve the approximate problem, the algorithm uses one of two main types of steps at each iteration:

A direct step in (x, s). This step attempts to solve the KKT equations, [Equation 3-2](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/first-order-optimality-measure.html#brhkghv-48) and [Equation 3-3](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/first-order-optimality-measure.html#brhkghv-49), for the approximate problem via a linear approximation. This is also called a Newton step.

Then it says

[image]

As it says the last equation is obtained by trying to solve the KKT conditions. Can anyone help me how it is solved to get the above results?